# Make /storage folder publically available in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I make `/storage`  folder public? I already have a symlink inside `/public` folder but it's still redirecting to login page when I try to access `storage/Docs/Components/Document.md`

Comment: your symlink is `projectroot/public/storage -> projectroot/storage/app/public`?

Comment: Yes. I ran `php artisan storage:link` to make this

Answer (score 0):

Auth should only be coming into play if the request is being handed off to Laravel from the webserver, meaning a file or folder at the path provided does not exist or is not accessible. Not sure how that path would translate in your routes to something that needs auth though.

Check the permissions for this file `projectroot/storage/app/public/Docs/Components/Document.md` and the folders it is in.

Comment: Don't think permission is the issue. I just changes it to 777 and still getting error. I just want a direct link to /public/storage directory

Comment: the only reason Laravel should be involved with the request (assuming a correctly configured server) is when a file or directory at that path is not accessible, apparently the webserver can't reach it for some reason or doesn't think it exists

Comment: Is that something to do with cache? I just deleted the storage folder and rerun `php artisan storage:link` but still no luck

Comment: you deleted the storage link and then made a new symlink?  but there is no laravel cache that has to do with static files the webserver should be handling

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that I was using homestead to do my development. I went inside my virtual machine and remove `public/storage` and rerun `php artisan storage:link` it works perfectly.